# scheduled mysql repair drawbacks?

Tags: mysql, linux

General question:

Is it safe to regularly run a mysql repair command?
This is my bash script that is added to the crontab scheduler to execute:

```
while read line; do

  # skip database tables that are okay
  echo "$line"|grep -q OK$ && continue

  echo "WARNING: $line"
done < <(mysqlcheck -u cron -p1234 -A --auto-repair)
```

Like create a bash script that repairs mysql every hour.

Does it have a negative effect on the database itself?

Thanks,

Comment: If you are into have table locks, go for it: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlcheck.html (Read locks) ... also fires off Analyze Table. On uber huge tables, that is not an option for your cron thing

Comment: And ... *"good grief(!), why do you feel (or, worse yet, find(!)) the need to do such a thing?!?!?!"*

Answer (score 2):

Client 1: (mimics the mysqlcheck)

```
lock tables category read;
select count(*) from category;
  ...
  ... do stuff
  ... 
unlock tables;
```

Client 2:
(while Client 1 has the Read Lock, prior to `unlock tables`)

```
mysql> insert category(category_name,parent_id) values ('z',1);
(... Client 1 finally performs the `unlock tables`)

Query OK, 1 row affected (12 min 20.93 sec)
```

So that is the experience you may have.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify the opinion expressed by my previous thread-comment: *"it is not at all clear to me why you find it necessary to 'repair(!)' your database 'every(!!) hour(!!)' *(or, at all ...)*." If you **do** "find yourself in such a disagreeable situation," then you had damm-well better find out *why!*

And, as to the question of *“does it have a negative effect on the database itself?”* my answer would be that the answer *could* “definitely be ‘Yes.’” **(But(!)** that is merely my experiential opinion!)

By and large, the data-structures of a database are intended to be *self-maintaining* over a very long period of time. *“Frequent* analysis and/or optimization” should no more be necessary, on a database, than “frequent de-fragmentation” should be necessary on a *(modern...)* file system. The algorithms are designed to *selectively* adjust the internal statistics-counters on a *case-wise* basis, in order to “self-tune” the system to *consistently* produce “good enough” performance without draconian intervention.

In my opinion, operations such as `mysqlcheck` should only be performed after *pervasive* changes have been made to the database contents, such as a mass-delete or mass-insert. And, the object of your quest should *never* be "repair."